# One POJO for two different JSONs using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

JSON 1:

```
[
    {
        "a": 23118,
        "b": "3373141",
        "c": "abcd",
        "d": "d_name",
        "override": false,
        "qty1": 2000.0,
        "qty2": 2000.0,
        "qty3": 2000.0,
        "qty4": 2000.0,
        "update": "01:00:00"
    },
    {},
    {},
    ...
]
```

JSON 2:

```
[
    {
        "e": 2317418,
        "f": "XYZ",
        "g": "abcdef",
        "h": "h_name",
        "override": false,
        "qty1": 2000.0,
        "qty2": 2000.0,
        "qty3": 2000.0,
        "qty4": 2000.0
    },
    {},
    {},
    ...
]
```

Code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
responsePOJO responsePOJOObj = objectMapper.readValue(JSONString, responsePOJO.class);
```

Is it possible to convert JSON 1 and JSON 2 using one POJO class? Or I have to create two different POJOs?

Comment: What's the _slight_ difference?

Comment: Could you please format your JSON?

Comment: Yes, you will need two POJOs or a custom deserializer that can parse from two property names.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 15 fields in my original JSON 1 and JSON 2 are same whereas only 4 fields are different in both.

Comment: With a custom deserializer, you can check to see whether e/f/g/h or a/b/c/d exist in the JSON and assign the respective values independently.

Comment: An example of custom deserializer would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown what your `responsePOJO` class looks like but yes you can.  What you can do is create all of your known fields as usual and then have the unknowns stored as a map and make use of Jacksons `JsonAnySetter` annotation.

An example of this would be something like storing the other fields in a map, like this:

```
private Map<String, Object> otherFields = new HashMap<>();

@JsonAnySetter
public void set(String name, Object value) {
    otherFields.put(name, value)
}
```

Jackson will then call this `set` method for any field it can't find in your standard field list

Answer (score 0):

If just some fields differ, I would suggest using 2 POJO with a common parent class containing the common fields.

```
abstract class PojoParent {
    int qty1;
    int qty2;
    boolean override;
    ...
}

class Pojo1 extends PojoParent {
    String a;
    ...
}

class Pojo2 extends PojoParent {
    String e;
    ...
}
```

There's probably some tricks to do it with only one class but I'd advise going with the most simple and comprehensive solution.

Comment: While this will work during serialization, this won't work during deserialization since you cannot know which subclass to use when the string content is dynamic.

Comment: Good point. To use this, you'll have to use `@JsonTypeInfo` et `@JsonSubTypes` annotations, but then you'll have to introduce an extra discriminator field to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class PojoDeserialize {

    public static class ResponsePOJO {
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public String a;
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public String b;
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public String c;
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public String d;
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public String e;
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public String f;
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public String g;
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public String h;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json1 = "{\"a\": 23118,\"b\": \"3373141\",\"c\": \"abcd\",\"d\": \"d_name\"}";
        ResponsePOJO resp1 = objectMapper.readValue(json1, ResponsePOJO.class);
        assert resp1.a != null;
        assert resp1.b != null;
        assert resp1.c != null;
        assert resp1.d != null;
        assert resp1.e == null;
        assert resp1.f == null;
        assert resp1.g == null;
        assert resp1.h == null;
        String json2 = "{\"e\": 2317418,\"f\": \"XYZ\",\"g\": \"abcdef\",\"h\": \"h_name\"}";
        ResponsePOJO resp2 = objectMapper.readValue(json2, ResponsePOJO.class);
        assert resp2.a == null;
        assert resp2.b == null;
        assert resp2.c == null;
        assert resp2.d == null;
        assert resp2.e != null;
        assert resp2.f != null;
        assert resp2.g != null;
        assert resp2.h != null;
    }

}
```

So this way you can keep one class but convert two different JSON strings.